# How to allow .js file upload in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mime-types

So I successfully added svg to my allowed mime types. But I can't get my head around allow js files. It still gives me an error: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

```
function add_custom_upload_mimes( $mime_types ) {

    $mime_types['js'] = 'application/x-javascript';
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mime_types;

}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes', 1, 1 );
```

Comment: That's a valid error message, application types are not safe to upload. Also, it's not a problem with your coding and we don't deal with bypassing security here.

Comment: Thnx; it was planning to allow this for admins. But I see that this would mean a security thread.